# How to get the key from childByAutoID() in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase to upload data into database, using this:

`REF_SESSIONS.childByAutoId().updateChildValues([my data])`

Is there a way to get that key value? I want to save it into coreData.

would this work?

```
let sessionKey = REF_SESSIONS.childByAutoId().key
REF_SESSIONS.child(sessionKey!).updateChildValues([my data])
```

Comment: You have to be specific about child id. `childByAutoId` is used for creating a new Child in Firebase. Post screenshot of your Firebase database and what you are trying to achieve. So that we can help you :)

Comment: Yes, that would work. Calling `childByAutoId()` return a new database location, and calling `key` on that will return its key.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a new node, getting the key, and then populating it with data:

```
let key = REF_SESSIONS.childByAutoId().key
REF_SESSIONS.child(key).updateChildValues([my data])
```